# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened when opening a channel in jsch

Tags: java, jsch

When connecting to a remote host using jsch version 0.1.51 we occasionally run into the following exception when calling `Channel.connect()` on a `ChannelExec`.

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened.
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.sendChannelOpen(Channel.java:765)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:151)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
```

The code we use after the session has been created is:

```
ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
channel.setCommand("echo hello");
channel.connect(); // Error here
```

The `Channel.connect()` call usually returns in under 100 ms, but when this error ocurrs the call hangs for more than 20 seconds before throwing the exception.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The exception message is slightly misleading. The error can occur when there is a timeout waiting for the `SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION` message from the server. The default timeout in jsch (version 0.1.51) is 20 seconds. I think there are other situations where the same error occurrs but I have not investigated further.

While there probably can be numerous reasons for the timeout, we have seen it caused by reverse DNS lookups in sshd from OpenSSH that took a long time occasionally.

That cause can be resolved by disabling DNS lookups from sshd by setting

```
UseDNS no
```

in your sshd_config (typically `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). This is generally safe to do according to what *Gilles* writes in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56941/what-is-the-point-of-sshd-usedns-option) thread.

Another option is to increase the timeout when connecting the channel. `Channel.connect` accepts a timeout argument (milliseconds), e.g. `channel.connect(60000)`. This can be useful if you do not control the server you are connecting to.

Comment: Good point with the time unit, in my case I had specified the timeout in seconds instead of milliseconds.